# Unmarshalling a simple XML

Tags: java, jaxb, jaxb2

I am having hard time unmarshalling the following XML using JAXB. This is the xml which is having only one field with an attribute. I have referred many tutorials where they only do an example of reading a string in fields which s not helpful in my case.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>  
<CircuitImpactConfigs id="1">
    <Objects>
        <Object type="1" impactAnalysisDataBuilderClassName="tttttttt"/>
        <Object type="2" impactAnalysisDataBuilderClassName="yyyyyyyyy"/>
        <Object type="3" impactAnalysisDataBuilderClassName="eeeeeee" />
        <Object type="4" impactAnalysisDataBuilderClassName="iiiiiiiii"/>
        <Object type="5" impactAnalysisDataBuilderClassName="rrrrrrrrrr"/>
        <Object type="6" impactAnalysisDataBuilderClassName="zzzzzz"/>
        <Object type="7" impactAnalysisDataBuilderClassName="qqqqqqqqqqq"/>
    </Objects>

    <ForceSwitchMode name="FORCE_SWITCHED" />

</CircuitImpactConfigs>
```

Based on what i learnt from tutorial 
My Classes are CircuitImpactConfigs.java

```
   import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name = "CircuitImpactConfigs")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class CircuitImpactConfigs {

    private ForceSwitchMode ForceSwitchMode;
    List<Obj> Object;

    @XmlElement
    public List<Obj> getObject() {
        return Object;
    }

    public void setObject(List<Obj> object) {
        Object = object;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public ForceSwitchMode getForceSwitchMode() {
        return ForceSwitchMode;
    }

    public void setForceSwitchMode(ForceSwitchMode forceSwitchMode) {
        ForceSwitchMode = forceSwitchMode;
    }


}
```

and

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;

public class ForceSwitchMode {

    private String name;

    @XmlAttribute
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

and

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;

public class Obj {
    String type;
    String impactAnalysisDataBuilderClassName;

    @XmlAttribute
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @XmlAttribute
    public String getImpactAnalysisDataBuilderClassName() {
        return impactAnalysisDataBuilderClassName;
    }

    public void setImpactAnalysisDataBuilderClassName(String impactAnalysisDataBuilderClassName) {
        this.impactAnalysisDataBuilderClassName = impactAnalysisDataBuilderClassName;
    }

}
```

I am getting null list when doing the unmarshalling. This is the class where i create the JAXBcontext object and create unmarshalling object.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

public class CircuitImpactConfUnmarshaller {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {
        File file = new File("CircuitImpact.xml");
        System.out.println(file.exists());
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(CircuitImpactConfigs.class);
        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        CircuitImpactConfigs que = (CircuitImpactConfigs) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);

        System.out.println(que.getForceSwitchMode().getName());
        List<Obj> list = que.getObject();
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

the last print statement is giving null. I understand i am doing something wrong in the `class Obj`

Comment: i found the issue with null pointer exception in this line

Comment: `System.out.println(que.getForceSwitchMode().getName());`

Comment: Thanks @wero. i did the changes in the edit mode to the question

Comment: `List<Obj> Object` should be `List<Obj> Objects`. Not the main problem but a signioficant one.

Comment: This xml have other tags than in the example XML? If yes... you have the xsd for this xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JAXB uses implicit naming conventions and explicit annotations to define a mapping between a XML and a Java structure.

Either element and attribute names in the XML match field names in Java (match by naming convention) or you need to use annotations to establish the mapping.

The Java list `CircuitImpactConfigs.Object` is not getting filled because the mapping failed, since the corresponding element in the XML is named `Objects`.

You can now either rename `CircuitImpactConfigs.Object` to `CircuitImpactConfigs.Objects` or use the name parameter of a JAXB annotation to define the corresponding name:

```
@XmlElement(name="Objects")
public List<Obj> getObject() {
```

---

EDIT: As you indicate in your comments there are still other mapping issues with your code. I would suggest that you adapt another approach:

1. Create a CircuitImpactConfigs object with all subobjects filled.
2. **Marhsall** that object to a XML file.
3. Check that the XML is in the expected format. If not, tweak the mapping.

Following this approach you can be sure that a XML file in the desired format can be unmarshalled to your Java structure. The code to marshall is

```
CircuitImpactConfigs que = ...
Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
marshaller.marshal(que, System.out);
```

Comment: Thanks @wero. I changed the `CircuitImpactConfigs.Object ` to `CircuitImpactConfigs.Objects` .  Well it is creating a list now. But the "type" and "impactAnalysisDataBuilderClassName" are coming as null. I suspect i messing this up because "Objects" tag is having many "Object" tags with attributes in it. So i should be having seperate class for "Objects" and "Object" ?? Please clarify..

Comment: Thanks @wero. I tried marshalling the same XML. It helped me a lot to understand the mapping. Thanks a lot mate.